# How to change the size of the right/main column in the koma-moderncvclassic?

Tags: koma-script, moderncv, columns, width

I am using the koma-moderncvclassic package to re-create my CV. How can I manipulate the size of the right side column using so the column width matches the page layout respectively the width of the header? Here my MWS:

```
\documentclass[%
parskip=half,%
fontsize=11pt,%
a4paper,%
pagesize,%
headinclude,footinclude,%
headings=normal,%
]{scrreprt}

\newcommand*{\firstname}{Max}
\newcommand*{\familyname}{Muster}
\newcommand*{\addressstreet}{Muster Allee 111}
\newcommand*{\addresscity}{11111 Musterstadt}
\newcommand*{\address}[2]{\addressstreet{#1}\addresscity{#2}}
\newcommand*{\mobile}{+49 1234567}
\newcommand*{\email}{mustermann@muster.de}

%left column width (default value: 2,79cm)
\newlength\myhintscolumnwidth%
\setlength\myhintscolumnwidth{.21\textwidth}

\usepackage[myblue]{koma-moderncvclassic} 

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm} 

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ohead{\footnotesize \firstname~\familyname\\ \addressstreet,~\addresscity \\\emailsymbol~\email~\phonesymbol~\mobile}
\setheadsepline{0.3pt} 

\begin{document}

\section{Work experience}
\cventry{01/2015 - 04/2015}{degree/jobtitle}{institution/employer}{localization}{optional: grade/...}{optional: comment/job description}
\cventry{01/2015 - 04/2015}{degree/jobtitle}{institution/employer}{localization}{optional: grade/...}{optional: comment/job description}

\section{Education}
\cventry{01/2015 - 04/2015}{degree/jobtitle}{institution/employer}{localization}{optional: grade/...}{optional: comment/job description}
\cventry{01/2015 - 04/2015}{degree/jobtitle}{institution/employer}{localization}{optional: grade/...}{optional: comment/job description}

\section{IT Skills}
\cvline{Very good}{MS Office (Excel, Word, PowerPoint, Outlook), OpenOffice. MS Office (Excel, Word, PowerPoint, Outlook), OpenOffice.}
\cvline{Good}{MS SharePoint, MS Project, MS Office (Excel, Word, PowerPoint, Outlook) MS Office (Excel, Word, PowerPoint, Outlook)}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the order of the packages:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm} 

\usepackage[myblue]{koma-moderncvclassic}
```

So the package `koma-moderncvclassic` can calculate the `maincolumnwidth` depending on your resulting `textwidth`.

[image]